как можно подключить ночной режим в яндекс карте с оберткой @pbe/react-yandex-maps?
     <Map
  defaultState={defaultState}
  height='90%'
  instanceRef={mapRef}
  modules={['geoObject.addon.balloon', 'geoObject.addon.hint']}
  options={{
    restrictMapArea: [
      [85.23618, -178.9],
      [-73.87011, 181],
    ],
  }}
  width='100%'
>
  {data.length
    ? data.map(point => (
        <Placemark
          key={point.id}
          data={data.find(item => item.id === point.id)}
          geometry={[point.lat, point.lon]}
          id={point.id}
        />
      ))
    : null}
  <ZoomControl
    options={{
      position: { left: 20, top: 100 },
      size: 'large',
    }}
  />
</Map>


Обёртка pbe/react-yandex-maps работает с JS API Яндекс Карт версии 2.1. Это версия с пререндеренной подложкой, не поддерживающей кастомизацию. Потому включить на такой карте ночной режим возможности нет даже нативными методами API.

Большое спасибо!

а в принципе тему можно как-то поменять ? сам цвет карты

В 2.1 подложка одного единственного цвета, она не меняется. Если нужно настроить карту, используйте API 3.0 https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/dg/concepts/customization
